# How to calculate occurrences between evenly-spaced intervals with set start/end points using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to create a timeline of events over the past day with a series of dates. Each date is considered an occurrence of an event. Occurrences need to be grouped by the hour. I need to include zero values in the timeline.

**Sample Data**

```
items = [
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 16, 51, 48),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 17, 25, 19),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 20, 6, 33, 35),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 23, 21, 35),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 15, 8, 41),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 21, 44, 16),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 19, 18, 21, 28),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 20, 7, 20, 22),
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 20, 11, 15, 43)
]
```

Right now, I have it working, but this doesn't feel like the correct way to do this. Any advice?

**Current solution**

```
import pandas as pd

def _generate_timeseries(items, start_ts, end_ts):
    # add start/end times to the data
    items.insert(0, start_ts)
    items.append(end_ts)

    # value each datetime as one occurrence
    data = [1 for x in range(len(items))]
    timeseries = pd.Series(data, index=items)
    hourly_data = timeseries.resample('H').sum()

    timeline = hourly_data.tolist()
    return [{'mentions': x} for x in timeline[1:-1]]
```

**Results Example**

```
timeline =[
    {'mentions': 4}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 0}, {'mentions': 3}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 0}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 0}, {'mentions': 14}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 4}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 3}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 1}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 6}, {'mentions': 2}, {'mentions': 2}
]
```

Comment: Is the "Results Example" generated from the given data in this question?

Comment: No, sorry, that's simply an example of the output. It doesn't use the data provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':items})
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Event',freq='H'))['Event'].count()
```

Output:

```
Event
2018-03-19 15:00:00    1
2018-03-19 16:00:00    1
2018-03-19 17:00:00    1
2018-03-19 18:00:00    1
2018-03-19 19:00:00    0
2018-03-19 20:00:00    0
2018-03-19 21:00:00    1
2018-03-19 22:00:00    0
2018-03-19 23:00:00    1
2018-03-20 00:00:00    0
2018-03-20 01:00:00    0
2018-03-20 02:00:00    0
2018-03-20 03:00:00    0
2018-03-20 04:00:00    0
2018-03-20 05:00:00    0
2018-03-20 06:00:00    1
2018-03-20 07:00:00    1
2018-03-20 08:00:00    0
2018-03-20 09:00:00    0
2018-03-20 10:00:00    0
2018-03-20 11:00:00    1
Freq: H, Name: Event, dtype: int64
```

#### Edit to get full days:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Event',freq='H'))['Event'].count()
  .reindex(pd.date_range(df.Event.dt.floor('D').min(), 
                         df.Event.dt.ceil('D').max(), 
                         freq='H')).fillna(0)
```

OUtput:

```
2018-03-19 00:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 01:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 02:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 03:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 04:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 05:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 06:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 07:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 08:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 09:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 10:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 11:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 12:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 13:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 14:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 15:00:00    1.0
2018-03-19 16:00:00    1.0
2018-03-19 17:00:00    1.0
2018-03-19 18:00:00    1.0
2018-03-19 19:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 20:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 21:00:00    1.0
2018-03-19 22:00:00    0.0
2018-03-19 23:00:00    1.0
2018-03-20 00:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 01:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 02:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 03:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 04:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 05:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 06:00:00    1.0
2018-03-20 07:00:00    1.0
2018-03-20 08:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 09:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 10:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 11:00:00    1.0
2018-03-20 12:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 13:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 14:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 15:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 16:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 17:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 18:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 19:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 20:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 21:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 22:00:00    0.0
2018-03-20 23:00:00    0.0
2018-03-21 00:00:00    0.0
Freq: H, Name: Event, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This looks correct except that it needs to include the "outer" time periods that aren't included in the sample data. That is, this doesn't cover the entire 24-hour day.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! This is nearly it. Would I take this and truncate the start/end with the dates specified in the `_generate_timeseries` function that I mentioned? The results should include 24 items.

Comment: @Jared.  Oh... so you want to group by hours of a day.  We can do that in the group by statement also.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.Event.dt.hour)['Event'].count().reindex(np.arange(24)).fillna(0)`